# Нужны ли какие-либо запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Это позволит закупать продукты более высокого качества для школ и больниц и оградить детей и пациентов от фальсификата.

Answer (score 2):

> *Это позволит закупать продукты более высокого качества для школ и больниц и оградить детей и пациентов от фальсификатора.*
>
> Нужны ли какие-либо запятые?

Запятые при таком порядке слов не нужны. Но лучше, по-моему, было бы написать примерно так:

***Это позволит закупать для школ и больниц продукты более высокого качества  и оградит детей и пациентов от фальсификата.***

Или так:

***Это позволит закупать для школ и больниц продукты более высокого качества, а также оградит детей и пациентов от фальсификата.***

Comment: Неплохо и просто исключить второе "и", добавив перед уточнением запятую. Если чем-то заменять это "и", логично выглядит "тем самым" (дети в школах, пациенты в больницах).

Comment: Вторая редакция смыслово неэквивалентна оригиналу.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны, но правильней: "**от** **фальсификатОВ**". Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

1.Александр ЗЮЗЯЕВ. По стране идет эпидемия алкогольных отравлений // Комсомольская правда, 2006.10.28   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
 Иллюзия, что люди стали меньше погибать от фальсификатов, тает просто на глазах. [Александр ЗЮЗЯЕВ. По стране идет эпидемия алкогольных отравлений // Комсомольская правда, 2006.10.28]

2.Яковлева Ольга. КРИМИНАЛЬНАЯ ПИЛЮЛЯ // Труд-7, 2003.02.28   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
 Таможня оградить рынок от фальсификатов не может―лицензии на право торговли давно уже навострились оформлять через отечественные офшоры: Алтай, Туву, Калмыкию. [Яковлева Ольга. КРИМИНАЛЬНАЯ ПИЛЮЛЯ // Труд-7, 2003.02.28]

3.ПРОХОДИМЦЫ НА ТАРАКАНЬЕМ ПРОМЫСЛЕ // Труд-7, 2000.09.29   [омонимия не снята]  Все примеры (1) 
 Различные средства лучше применять в комбинации: использовать не только аэрозоли, но и специальные ловушки с клейкими поверхностями―простое и безопасное для людей и домашних животных средство. - Как отличить эффективные средства от фальсификатов? - Нужно внимательно прочитать информацию на упаковке. [ПРОХОДИМЦЫ НА ТАРАКАНЬЕМ ПРОМЫСЛЕ // Труд-7, 2000.09.29]